# Typed.js installation without Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, typed.js

I am currently making a project that needs the JavaScript library [typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) but am also using the free webhost [000webhost](https://000webhost.com) which does not allow the use of Node.js. However, typed.js is installed using Yarn, NPM, or Bower, which to my knowledge needs Node.js.
Because of this, I would like to know how to install typed.js or have an alternative that is easy-to-use for someone who doesn't know much JavaScript.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah its easy, [download the library](https://codeload.github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/zip/master) in `zip` format, goto `/lib/` and find `typed.min.js`.

include this file as normal javascript file in your html

```
<script src="typed.min.js"></script>
```

Enjoy! all the functionalities. :)