# How do I use typed.js without jquery or needing a main.js file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typed.js

Not too experienced w/ HTML and was wondering how to use typed.js in just HTML/CSS, without any JS at all. I've downloaded a typed.min.js into my site root and was wondering how to actually set it up with strings, any help appreciated :)

I've already seen this: [Typed.js installation without Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111109/typed-js-installation-without-node-js) - and would like to know how to set it up if possible with a simple div/h2 tags

infact it seems i was being stupid, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply just include the library by referencing the script from their website, then inside a `<script>` tag, define a new `var` with var or `let` and use it as described in the docs (see below);

```js
var typed = new typed.js

var typed = new Typed('.element', {
  strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
  typeSpeed: 30
});


------------
// then where you want to use it,

<div id='coolStrings'>
  // stuff inide here
<div>
```

https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/ - here's the docs

Answer (score 0):

You have to first include the library then include a script after that to actually use it. Normally you would do this at the verry bottom of your page.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.9"></script>
<script>
  var typed = new Typed('#typed', {
     stringsElement: '#typed-strings'
  });
</script>
```

Then somewhere on your page where you want to use it...

```
<div id="typed-strings">
   <p>Typed.js is a <strong>JavaScript</strong> library.</p>
   <p>It <em>types</em> out sentences.</p>
</div>
<span id="typed"></span>
```

The docs explain this pretty well near the bottom for static HTML

https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/